# Model blocks using Accelerator, SIL or PIL mode are not supported in student mode

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a code example in Simulink, but I get the error:

> The model 'tester' contains a Model block. Model blocks using Accelerator, SIL or PIL mode are not supported in student mode.

Now it seems like from my google-research that there is also a "normal mode". I assume the model would in "normal mode" even with a student license. Is it possible to change mode of a model to "normal mode" and if so, how is it done? Or what are my other options (besides buying the professional version).

I am running Matlab 2014a Student Version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Double-click the model block and select "Normal" for Simulation Mode:

[image]

More details in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Hint for Mac users: I had to ctrl-click and then select "Block Parameters (ModelReference)" to find the dialog.